# Help with the following limit

Tags: limits, real-numbers

I have the following limit

$$ \lim_{u\to\infty} \frac{-bu^{a-1}e^u}{e^{be^u}} $$

*where a and b are constants*

I have tried L'Hopital and i keep getting undefined results. I have also tried Series expansions but nothing.

Could anyone take me through this , and how i am supposed to think when tackling a problem such as this?

Thank you very much for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

First suppose $b>0$.  For large $u$ we'll have $be^u>2u$, so
$$\frac{u^{a-1}e^u}{e^{be^u}}<\frac{u^{a-1}e^u}{e^{2u}}=\frac{u^{a-1}}{e^u}\to0\ .$$
If $b\le0$ then $e^{be^u}\le1$ so
$$\frac{u^{a-1}e^u}{e^{be^u}}\ge u^{a-1}e^u\to\infty\ .$$